# Tensorflow FIFOQueue '_4_batch_join/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow version : 1.0.0

```
    NUM_THREADS = 4
    BATCH_SIZE = 32
    csv_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(csv_files, shuffle=False)
    jpg_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(jpg_files, shuffle=False)
    data_batch_list = [read_data(csv_file_queue, jpg_file_queue) for _ in range(NUM_THREADS)]
    csv_data_batch, jpg_data_batch = tf.train.batch_join(data_batch_list, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    sess.run(tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()))

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
            ...
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_4_batch_join/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 32, current size 17)

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens when preparing the last batch. Add `allow_smaller_final_batch=True` to your `train.batch_join` invocation:
from the documentation:

> If allow_smaller_final_batch is True, a smaller batch value than
>   batch_size is returned when the queue is closed and there are not
>   enough elements to fill the batch, otherwise the pending elements are
>   discarded. In addition, all output tensors' static shapes, as accessed
>   via the get_shape method will have a first Dimension value of None,
>   and operations that depend on fixed batch_size would fail.